# How to use a Subject with stateful local data where its initial value comes from an Observable?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactivex

Given a class that maintains a local list of selected things and the initial value for those selected things comes from an Observable that does a network call to fetch it, how can I correctly use Subjects and Observables together?

This is what I want to public expose:

```
class SelectedThingsRepository {
    public let selectedThings: Observable<[Thing]>

    public toggleSelected(for thing: Thing)
}
```

My current thinking is that I should somehow use the network Observable to get the initial data, save it to a local variable, then on every call to `toggleSelected` I call the Subject's `onNext` passing the local variable that holds the list of selected values.

My current think is something like this:

```
var localList: [Thing] = [] // How can I initialize this from serverSelected?

let serverSelected = Observable<[Thing]>.create { observer in 
    thingNetwork.fetch { selectedList
        observer.onNext(selectedList)
        observer.onCompleted()
    }
}.shareReplay(1)

let localSelected = ReplaySubject.create(bufferSize: 1)

selectedThings = localSelected.ifEmpty(switchTo: serverSelected)

public func toggleSelected(for thing: Thing) {
    // ... change localList to add or remove thing
    localSelected.onNext(localList)
}
```

Note that I haven't initialized `localList` with the server data. I thought about doing it in the `thingNetwork.fetch` call back, just before calling `onNext` but it feels very wrong to have side effects there.

How can I do this? Bonus round: I'd love to have the network call performed only when `localSelected` has a first subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do:

```
class SelectedThingsRepository {

    public let selectedThings: Observable<[Thing]> 

    public func toggleSelected(for thing: Thing) {
        // I normally don't bother with a function like this
        // I usually expose the subject publicly and bind an observable to the subject.
        // ex:
        // someObservable
        //     .bindTo(selectedThingsRepositoryInstance.toggleSelectedSubject)
        //     .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        toggleSelectedSubject.onNext(thing)
    }

    private let toggleSelectedSubject = PublishSubject<Thing>()


    // I create this helper enum to make the Rx operations much easier 
    // I define a case for each unique operation or any different Type that will manipulate the selectedThings Observable
    // In this class, you have 2 operations, each with a different Type 

    enum ListChange {
        case replaceAll([Thing])
        case toggleOne(Thing)

        // other example operations I often use: 
        // case noChange
        // case clearAll
        // case toggleMultiple([Thing])
        // case sort( some sorting function)
        // case filter( some filtering function)
    }


init() {

    // I'm just declaring this here out of laziness
    // In reality, I use Dependency Injection 
    let thingNetwork = ThingNetwork()

    // I rarely create observables like this in here.
    // Usually I have a function in thingNetwork which returns the observable. and I 

    let serverList = Observable<[Thing]>.create { observer -> Disposable in
        thingNetwork.fetch { serverList in

            observer.onNext(serverList)
            observer.onCompleted()

        }
        return Disposables.create()

    }

// now the magic        

// 1. Setup all the possible ways that the observable will be updated
// and map these to the enum above that corresponds with how the source observable manipulates the resulting observable 

// I think of these as "Trigger" -> "Operation"
// where everything left of the final .map is a Trigger
// that results in an Operation to the selectedThings


selectedThings = Observable.from([
        serverList               .map{ serverList in return ListChange.replaceAll(serverList) },
        toggleSelectedSubject    .map{toggleThing in return ListChange.toggleOne(toggleThing) }
        ])
        .merge()

// 2. Using scan and enum switch, it becomes very easy to produce the next list of things
// If I need another operation for the array, I simply declare another enum case and add to the switch statement how to handle the case

        .scan( [Thing]() ) { previousList, listChange in

            switch listChange {
            case .replaceAll(let replacementList):
                return replacementList

            case .toggleOne(let toggledThing):
                // NOTE: depending on how exactly toggleSelected(for thing: Thing) is supposed to manipulate the array, your code here could be wildly different
                // In the end, you just need to return the resulting array post-toggle

                var updatedList = previousList

                // if selectedThing is in the list, remove selectedThing
                if let index = previousList.index(of: toggledThing) {
                    updatedList.remove(at: index)
                }
                else {
                    // otherwise, add selectedThing
                    updatedList.append(toggledThing)
                }

                return updatedList

            }

        }
        .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()



}
```

---

NOTE From this line on:

I personally avoid writing state-ful code unless I have to, so I don't actually use the solutions I thought of. There are probably better solutions than what I know.

Your initial requirements didn't need a state-ful localList variable. But if you have other code that will require this, you can use a Variable and bind the values of the Observable to the Variable

```
let localListVariable = Variable<[Thing]>([])

selectedThings
    .bindTo(localListVariable)
    // NOTE: this creates a disposable which you'll need to dispose
```

Then use localListVariable.value to get the most recent array of Things.

---

Bonus Round: 
The networking in fetch will only be called once selectedThings has a first subscriber.

Comment: This is a really nice answer. I'm still learning Rx so I'll need to re-read this a few times to totally grasp it. The reason I'm learning to handle state is that I know it will be impossible to have all my app converted to use observables, there is a lot of legacy code that I need to integrate.